# How to find optimal thread for a multicore system?

Tags: java

I was asked in an interview how many maximum threads can be configured in a 4 core system, if you are designing a multi threaded program?. Searched everywhere, couldn't find a good answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many threads as you want, the number of CPUs(actually the number of logical processors) will decide how many of them will run in the same time. Maybe you should read a bit about Thread Scheduling in Java.